# When unprotect error message: target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a master spreadsheetApp with a static (=does not change in structure, but only in content) Gsheet 'gameSchedule' with data in certain ranges.

Each player in our team has his own individual spreadsheetApp with a copy of the 'gameSchedule' where he is supposed to maintain his planned attendance to the games.

As I maintain the content of the 'gameSchedule' I want to release (=unprotect) some of the ranges to the players.

From the master Gsheet 'gameSchedule' my script collects the ranges which the players are supposed to maintain into array 'readyForEdit'.

When I try to unprotect the ranges in the individual player sheets with the statement:

`protection.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotect);`

I get an error saying that the target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet

'protection' is defined like this

```
...
 var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('GameSchedule');  
...
```

where 'sheet' is redefined for each player (in a loop).

Array 'unprotect' is based on 'readyForEdit' like this:

```
...
var unprotect = [];
...
for (var l = 0; l < 31; l++){
  unprotect[i] = readyForEdit[l].offset(0, columnsPerWeek *k );
};
...
```

I hope my explanation is reasonably understandable.

Thank you for any input.

How about this for a minimal reproducible example?

```
  //Source
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('GameSchedule');    
  var readyForEdit = [];  
  readyForEdit[0] = sourceSheet.getRange("E6:E12");


  //Destination spreadsheets
  var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheePlayerID);  
  var sheet = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('GameSchedule');

  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('GameSchedule');  

  var unprotect = [];

  unprotect[0] = readyForEdit[0].offset(0, 1);

  protection.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotect);
```

Comment: Need [mcve]....

Comment: Consider the error message "target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet"... you're working with multiple spreadsheets, so you need to be careful that the ranges are from the same spreadsheet. For every range in `unprotect`, make sure that `unprotect[i].getSheet().getParent().getId() === protection.getRange().getSheet().getParent().getId()`

Comment: @Diego: yes exactly. I am working with multiple spreadsheet. From the master sheet I build an array with ranges that I wish to unprotect in the individual players sheets. Example: from the master sheet get the range A1:A3 into the array and then I want to unprotect the range A1:A3 in the sheets of each indivdual player. Note: each player has his own spreadsheet.

Comment: I am suffering from a 'question ban' due to (I presume) poor question quality. This question has been assigned 1 down-vote which I would like to get rid off. What should I do in this particular case to fix this question? I do not dare delete it since it apparently does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by

```
unprotect[0] = sheet.getRange(readyForEdit[0].offset(0, 1).getA1Notation());
```